# nlp dictionary with sentiment score

Tags: dictionary, nlp

can anyone help to find the description of each value of dictionary.
https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/vader_sentiment_lexicon.txt

as in the below lines:

abuse   -3.2        0.6 [-4, -2, -3, -4, -3, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3]

abused  -2.3    0.64031 [-2, -2, -3, -2, -2, -4, -2, -2, -2, -2]

abuser  -2.6    0.4899  [-3, -2, -3, -3, -2, -3, -2, -2, -3, -3]

abusers -2.6    1.0198  [-2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -3, -4, -3, 0]

abuses  -2.6    0.66332 [-3, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -1, -2, -3, -3]

abusing -2.0    1.41421 [-1, -2, -2, -4, -4, -2, -3, -1, 1, -2]

abusive -3.2    0.74833 [-4, -3, -3, -4, -4, -3, -4, -2, -3, -2]

abusively   -2.8    0.6 [-3, -4, -3, -2, -3, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3]

which value is presenting the sentiments score and what about the values presented within square braces[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search turned out their [research paper](http://comp.social.gatech.edu/papers/icwsm14.vader.hutto.pdf) that explains this:

> We used a wisdom-of-the-crowd13 (WotC) approach (Surowiecki, 2004) to
>   acquire a valid point estimate for the sentiment valence (intensity)
>   of each context-free candidate feature. We collected intensity ratings
>   on each of our candidate lexical features from ten independent human
>   raters (for a total of 90,000+ ratings). Features were rated on a
>   scale from “[–4] Extremely Negative” to “[4] Extremely Positive”, with
>   allowance for “[0] Neutral (or Neither, N/A)”. Ratings were obtained
>   using Amazon Mechanical Turk (AMT), a micro-labor website where
>   workers perform minor tasks in exchange for a small amount of money...

So the 10 numbers in the [ ] are the sentiment intensity rating from 10 humans, and the first number after the word is the overall sentiment intensity ratiny.